# Providing GPS data to Core Location?

Tags: gps, core-location, gpsd

I have a home network in my RV, a GPS receiver on the roof, and a GPSd service running on my router advertising my exact coords, heading, etc to my home network. In an ideal world, I would like to write something that can consume that information and inform Core Location on either my macs or my iphones. I've looked and I can't seem to find a way to write a Core Location provider, is this not possible or am I not looking for the right terminology?